# java.io.IOException: Posted content length of 1130270 exceeds limit of 1048576

Tags: java

While uploading a file more than 1 MB i am getting this error.

`java.io.IOException: Posted content length of 1130270 exceeds limit of 1048576
    com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:172)
    com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:222)
    com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:109)
    com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:89)
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.Test_jsp._jspService(Test_jsp.java:211)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)`

Can anyone tell where i can find Limit?
How to change it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you provide source code?

Answer (score 2):

Um, read the manual?

http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.html

Every constructor of the class takes the limit, so you should be able to set it easily. If your framework is hiding the creation of the MultipartParser, then you'll have to let us know the framework if we are to help you.